# How to set value inside a formular

Tags: yii

I have following formular:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput()->hint('Bitte gib Deinen Namen ein')->label('Name') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->hint('Das Passwort,bitte') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->hint('Deine E-Mail-Adresse, bitte') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'zahl_down')->hint('Der zuletzt eingebene Wert:'.$zahl_down)?>         
<?= $form->field($model, 'zahl_up')->hint('Der zuletzt eingebene Wert:'.$zahl_up)?>     
<?= $form->field($model, 'iteration')->hint('Der zuletzt eingebene Wert:'.$iteration)?> 
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkBox() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'Urlaubsziel')->dropdownList([
    'USA' => 'USA', 
    'Mexico' => 'Mexico',
    'Deutschland' => 'Deutschland', 
    'England' => 'England',
    'Frankreich' => 'Frankreich',],['prompt'=>'Select Country']);?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'Geschlecht')->radioList([
'Herr' => 'Herr', 
'Frau' => 'Frau']);?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'Automarke')->checkboxList([
1 => 'Daimler', 
2 => 'BMW',
3 => 'Peugeot', 
4 => 'VW'
```

]);

How can I set a value inside a formular, for instance like this:

```
<input type="text" name="zahl_down" id="zahl" value="<?php  echo $value;?>"></p>
```

Comment: E.g. `$form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['value' => $someValue]);`

Comment: Thx a lot for ur help

Comment: Thx a lot!! Brilliant.It works

Comment: No problem. Happy coding )